# Python multiprocessing to binary gives bad scaling

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I need to run multiple instances of a binary in parallel. For this I am using python multiprocessing module. The binary itself has a parallelization which can be set using OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable. A minimalist example of my code is the following

```
import sys
import os
from numpy import *
import time
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def cal_dist(filename):

    tic = time.time()
    ################################### COPY THE INPUP FILE ########################################
    tree = ET.parse(inputfilename+'.feb')
    tree.write(filename+'.feb',xml_declaration=True,encoding="ISO-8859-1")

    ##################################### SUBMIT THE JOB ###########################################
    os.system('export OMP_NUM_THREADS=12')
    os.system('$HOME/febiosource-2.0/bin/febio2.lnx64 -noconfig -i ' + filename + '.feb -silent')

    toc = time.time()
    print "Job %s completed in %5.2f minutes" %(filename,(toc-tic)/60.);
    return

# INPUT PARAMETERS
inputfilename="main-step1"
tempfilename='temp';
nCPU=7;

for iter in range(0,1):

    ################################### PARALLEL PROCESSING STARTS ########################################

    # CREATE ALL THE PROCESSES,
    p=[];
    maxj=nCPU;
    for j in range(0,nCPU):
        p.append(Process(target=cal_dist, args=(tempfilename+str(j),)))

    # START THE PROCESSES,
    for j in range(0,nCPU):
        p[j].start();
        time.sleep(0.2);

    # JOIN THEM,
    for j in range(0,nCPU):
        p[j].join();

    ################################### PARALLEL PROCESSING ENDS ########################################
```

If I set OMP_NUM_THREADS=1, then increasing the nCPU gives a good scaling. That is,

for nCPU=1, job time=3.5 minutes

for nCPU=7, job time=4.2 minutes

However, if I set OMP_NUM_THREADS=12, then increasing the nCPU gives a very bad scaling. That is,

for nCPU=1, job time=3.4 minutes

for nCPU=5, job time=5.7 minutes

for nCPU=7, job time=7.5 minutes

Any ideas on how I can solve this issue? I really need to use high number of CPUs and OMP_NUM_THREADS for my actual problem (and I know that the architecture of computer is that each node has 12 processors and I run it on nCPU*12 number of processors.

Comment: Read up on the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). Python is a bad choice for parallel processing.

Comment: I was not familiar with GIL. Since this is a very simple parallel processing, I thought Python should do a fine job. Do you have any other recommendations for implementing what I have here?

Comment: @Ankush, You're not actually using Python threads here, you're using `multiprocessing`, so the GIL isn't relevant at all.

Comment: @Ankush, at Stack Overflow when asking questions try to minimize attached code snippet as described in help center here http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @dano I should have looked at [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) before saying anything, you're absolutely correct - right at the front it says it's intended to get around problems with the GIL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're overloading your CPUs. With nCPU set to 1 with `OMP_NUM_THREADS=12`, you're spawning one process that uses twelve threads, which means you're keeping all your CPUs fully saturated. When you set nCPU to 7 with `OMP_NUM_THREADS=12`, you're spawning seven processes that use twelve threads each, which means you've got `12 * 7 = 84` threads running in parallel, fighting over 12 CPUs. My guess is this is creating a high context-switching overhead for the OS, and that's slowing you down.

With only 12 CPUs to work with, you're going to get diminishing returns if you try to run more than 12 threads+processes in parallel. (Unless a bunch of the work being done is I/O-bound, which doesn't seem to be the case here.)

Comment: For the case of 12*7, I assign 7 nodes=84 processors to my job. So, I don't think that should be a problem.

Comment: @Ankush I'm not sure what you mean. The `multiprocessing` module just creates processes on one single node (I'm assuming node means computer, in this case). How are other nodes being pulled in here?

Comment: By assigning I mean I am running on a cluster and I request 7nodes = 84processors. I am assuming that the `multiprocessing` module uses all of those nodes. Could that be a problem here? Since I don't need any memory sharing between the my processes I thought my code should work fine.

Comment: @Ankush The `multiprocessing` module doesn't know anything about your cluster. It can only create multiple processes on a single machine (node). If you want to spread the work across multiple nodes in a cluster, you should consider using something like [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) for distributing the work.

Comment: OK thanks for that clarification. I will look into celery or some other alternative.